# Intel Android Atom(x86) emulator HANG Mac OS X 10.9

Tags: android, android-emulator

Intel Android Atom(x86) emulator keeps hanging Mac OS X 10.9. As the HAXM release notes told which supports "OS X* 10.6 or 10.7 or 10.8 (32/64-bit)". I believe which does not support Mac OS X 10.9, but can anybody confirm? Thanks.

Comment: James Please see my answer below. That fixed my problem on Mac OSX 10.9.

Comment: Hi Bms270, worked! Thank you!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Intel just released a new patch for 10.9 which has fixed this issue. Download it below and your issue should be fixed after installation.

http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager

Also, before re-launching the emulator, make sure you delete all emulators and re-create them. If you have hard time deleting the emulators (if AVD Manager says it's running) you can delete them by following the steps below:

- Find the .android folder in your $HOME directory.
- In .android there should be a avd folder In the avd folder should be one or multiple .ini file and a corresponding *.avd virtual device folder.
- Delete both the .ini file and the .avd folder you want to get rid of.
- Return to the Android sdk and AVD manager.

Comment: An funny issue: while using both my laptop's display and an external DELL 24XX display, the emulator panic!

Comment: Never thought to delete the old emulators.  Thank you!

Comment: key thing apparently is deleting the old avd and recreating it. :(

Answer (score 1):

It hangs also my OSX 10.9, so far no solution. But there were problems also on older X versions: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=37826